# What are the things which are decisive in call during function overloading?

Tags: c++, overloading

I just wanted to know What are the factors decisive in making a function call during
overloading. As I know its the signature of parameters, number of parameters passed 
Which plays an important role. But is there the const part also Which plays an important 
part in overloading or not. Overloading of 1st and 2nd function works fine but if a add 
a third function with const as a characteristic in passed parameters, I get compilation error.  `int A::sum(int, int) and int A::sum(int, int) cannot be overloaded`. Just giving the code snippet for class:

```
class A
{
    private:
    int x;
    int y;

    public:
    int sum ( int a, int b )
    {
        cout << " Inside 1st ";
        return (a+b) ;
    }

    int sum (int a ,int b) const
    {
        cout << " Inside 2nd ";
        return (a+b) ;
    }

    int sum (const int a ,const int b)
    {
        cout << " Inside 3rd ";
        return (a+b) ;
    }

    A(){x=0;y=0;}
    ~A(){};
};
```

When I declare the normal object and make a call to sum the first function gets called and in case of a const object second sum is being called. That's perfectly fine. But if I write 1st and 3rd function both it becomes an issue. Why so?

Comment: Just as a note, when you *declare* a function as `void f(T);`, you can *define* it as `void f(T const x) { /* ... */ }`. In other words, the constness of a value parameter is an implementation detail, as it only affects the constness of the local variable inside the function scope and has nothing to do with how the function is *called*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overload on `const`-ness, but only where it actually makes a difference.  What do I mean "actually makes a difference"?  Well, if you declare

```
void foo(char *ptr);
void foo(const char *ptr);
```

the `const` matters: you are saying that one overload of `foo` guarantees not to modify the memory that `ptr` *points to*, and the other doesn't.  But if you declare

```
void foo(int x);
void foo(const int x);
```

the `const` *doesn't* matter: scalar arguments are always passed by value, so neither hypothetical variation of `foo` can modify the value of `x` in its caller, even if it wanted to.  Therefore, the C++ standard says that the `const` is discarded, and these are two different declarations of the *same function*, one of which is erroneous.

The position of the `const` relative to the `*` matters.  A pointer is itself a scalar, so these are also two declarations of the same function:

```
void foo(char *ptr);
void foo(char *const ptr);
```

because here the `const` qualifies the pointer itself rather than the object it points to.

That brings us to methods: a `const` qualifier after the argument list on a method declaration applies to the object pointed to by `this`, and that can be overloaded on:

```
struct A
{
  int foo (char *ptr);
  int foo (char *ptr) const;
  int foo (const char *ptr);
  int foo (const char *ptr) const;
};
```

You should think of these declarations as being rewritten internally to:

```
struct A {};
int A_foo (A *this, char *ptr);
int A_foo (const A *this, char *ptr);
int A_foo (A *this, const char *ptr);
int A_foo (const A *this, const char *ptr);
```

and then everything works according to the normal rules for overloaded functions.

Comment: Wonderful Explanation Zack , Will just check things practically . Hope it will clear all my doubts.

Answer (score 2):

`const` and non `const` functions can be overloaded.(`const` follows after the function)
i.e. it is a valid criteria for function overloading.

However, functions in your example cannot be overloaded on the basis of `const`ness of function arguments, because the constness of the arguments does not matter at all.The function argument is passed by value and the function receives a *copy* of it.
Function overloading needs that there should be some distinguishing criteria between *same named* functions, Unless the `const` on argument actually makes the functions being overloaded distinct from the perspective of the compiler the overloading using const-ness of function argument is not allowed.

The former is possible because,
If you have a `const` object then you You can only call a `const` function on it. Because a non-const function is bound to modify class members and hence calling it on const object is a semantic error and would results in compilation error.

If you have a normal on-const object then both the `const` and the non-const versions of the functions are valid to be called on the instance. The compiler chooses the most appropriate one which is the non-const version.

Comment: is there any specific reason Why compiler does not allow us to do overloading on basis of `constness` of parameter ?

Comment: Something I've wondered about, and which you might be in a position to answer, is overloading/inheritance and access control.  My experience indicates that if foo is `protected` in a base class, making foo `public` in a derived class will not overload it.  But what is the general rule?

Comment: @Als Thanks Als, i got your point but my question is Why compiler doesnot allow me to use the third function with const parameter passed in it ?

Comment: This answer is rather misleading -- you *can* overload on constness of arguments, but only when the `const` actually matters, e.g. when it's "pointer to T" versus "pointer to const T".  Overloading on `const` after the argument list *is* overloading on the constness of a parameter: the implicit `this` parameter.

Comment: @Ritesh: Because it does not make any difference as the parameters in your case are passed by value.Your function receives a copy of the original argument being passed, so the const does not matter here.

Comment: @Zack: well, *You can when it matters* implicitly means where there is a overloading criteria i.e where the two versions of the functions do something different. It boils down to the same.I will clarify a bit more. Just in case,

Comment: @MattPhillips: You cannot overload functions across classes, If you have same named function across, Base class & Derived class then the Derived class version of the function *hides* the Base class version.Lookup **Function Hiding**.